# Inject ApplicationDbContext into Configure method in Startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0-preview2-final and I would like to inject the ApplicationDbContext into Configure method in Startup class.

Here's my code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext context)
{ 
    // rest of my code
}
```

but when I run my app I'm getting an error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'ProjectName.Models.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider.

Here's also my code from ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            }
            else
            {
                options.UseSqlite("Data Source=travelingowe.db");
            }
        });
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work in 2.0.0 RTM. We've made it so that there is a scope during the call to Configure so the code you originally wrote will work. See https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/1106 for more details.

Answer (score 5):

EF Core `DbContext` is registered with scoped lifestyle. In ASP native DI container scope is connected to instance of `IServiceProvider`. Normally when you use your `DbContext` from Controller there is no problem because ASP creates new scope (new instance of `IServiceProvider`) for each request and then uses it to resolve everything within this request. However during application startup you don't have request scope so you should create scope yourself. You can do it like this:

```
var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    // rest of your code
}
```

**EDIT**

As davidfowl stated this will work in 2.0.0 RTM since scoped service provider will be created for `Configure` method.