# Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider. ASP.NET MVC app App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am doing Store application with Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 6th Edition by Adam Freeman. The example in book is made in Core 1.0, and I am using Core 3.0. I get error as below, while trying to seed data to my database (entityFramework).

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'BookStore.Models.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider.'

Below is my code:

```
 public class SeedData
    {
        public static void EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            if (!context.Products.Any())
            {
                context.Products.AddRange(
                    new Product {
                        Name = "Witcher",
                        Description = "Geralt the Witcher",
                        Category = "Fantasy",
                        Price = 30 }
                    );
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Startup Class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:BookStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}");
        });
        SeedData.EnsurePopulated(app);
    }
}
```

And Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

I am rather new in dependency injection so some explanation what is happening would be nice. I am searchin answer online for more than two hours without any result.

And more about the error:

> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type
>   serviceType, IServiceScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   BookStore.Models.SeedData.EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app) in
>   C:\Users\Piotr\source\repos\Store\BookStore\Models\SeedData.cs:line 12
>   at BookStore.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
>   ApplicationDbContext context) in
>   C:\Users\Piotr\source\repos\Store\BookStore\Startup.cs:line 51    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__31.MoveNext()

So the solution was:

```
var scopeeee = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();

ApplicationDbContext context = scopeeee.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Added at the beggining of EnsurePopulated method. Thanks!

Comment: `AddDbContext` internally calls `AddScoped`, so your `DbContext` is only available to classes and types that are created per-request (such as `Controller`), other request-scoped services, or transient services created in the context of a request, but not singleton services or other DI constructor calls outside of a request context.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231235/inject-applicationdbcontext-into-configure-method-in-startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231235/inject-applicationdbcontext-into-configure-method-in-startup) Please check this link, I think it will help you alot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create scope in `EnsurePopulated` method and then get instance from this scope.