# why do I get Exception when resolve my service in Config method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-core-3.0

I have WebApi project and this is my dependancy registration code:

```
public  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(opt=> opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conStr")));
            services.RegisterEasyNetQ("host=localhost;username=admin;password=admin");
            services.AddTransient(typeof(CreateOrderHandler));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(OrderFinishedHandler));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(OrderPaidHandler));
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

and I resolve these services run immediately after the project started by this code:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

            app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(CreateOrderHandler));
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(OrderPaidHandler));
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(OrderFinishedHandler));

        }
```

this code works properly when I run my project by **dotnet** command but when i am debugging my code in rider I am getting this Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'ApiProject.Order.CreateOrderHandler' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'ApiProject.Order.MyDatabaseContext'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider. ASP.NET MVC app App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903641/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-asp-net-mvc-app-app)

Comment: no. this code properly in debug mode also I want to inject MyDatabaseContext inside my handlers.